# how does one predict edges / links / connections on a weighted directed graph network?

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graph, adjacency-matrix

Given an adjacency matrix A for a weighted, directed graph (so matrix elements are not just 0/1 and the matrix is not symmetric), are there any good methods for predicting new edges?

I have a VERY large (billions of nodes) dataset with known edges for some connections and NULL values for unobserved connections, and I would like to use the known edges to make predictions of the unobserved ones.

It is fine if the method is not exact -- in fact, I would like to keep edges NULL or 0 if the prediction is below some threshold, just to keep the matrix as sparse as possible for data size and processing speed.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I think such an algorithm must be very expensive. I'd say that one has to calculate shortest path between two nodes and if it is lower as a given "treshold" length, lets say 2, there is high probability that those nodes might connect as well... but this is highly depended on your context. In a link graph my assumption might be right, but for other networks there is probably a higher possibility for farther away nodes to connect and a lesser probability for near nodes. Can you specify your scenario and why it is important for you to predict edges? That would help for a feasible algorithm design

Comment: Let's say I'd like to replicate Facebook, Google+, and LinkedIn's friend recommendations.  "Based on your friends, you may know the following people".  I'd like to construct this for an entire network, calculating the probability of a link for every pair.  I don't think that I want to skip pairs, although my final output would skip reporting links below a threshold for saving disk space.

Comment: I see. Hm... I think I would make a 2 step BFS from the person. afterwards one can calculate all shortest path (max length 2) between the person any layer 2 persons. if no path of length 1 exists count the number of length 2 paths. the "guys" with the highest amount of length 2 paths might be new edges... my thoughts for that. you even can adapt this for wider ranges and so on. this process should be cheap, because 2 step BFS is it and shortest path with length max of 2 is cheap as well.

Answer (score 1):

you may wish to delve into random graph generation and graph mining literature, notably works on scale-free networks. a quick internet search produced some papers which might be of relevance.

- [An overview](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/research/pdf/08-08.pdf) of real-world dynamic networks wrt their properties, suitable models and analysis techniques.
- [The seminal paper](http://www3.nd.edu/~networks/Publication%20Categories/03%20Journal%20Articles/Physics/EmergenceRandom_Science%20286,%20509-512%20%281999%29.pdf) on scale-free networks.
- [This survey article](http://web.cse.msu.edu/~cse835/Papers/Graph%20Mining%20Laws,%20Generators,%20and%20Algorithms.pdf) focuses on properties of realistic graphs that could be exploited in synthetic graph generation.
- [This paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~jure/pubs/kronecker-pkdd05.pdf) addresses densification and shrinking diameter the authors claim to be frequent in large real-world graphs. test cases are cited.
- [This paper](http://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/tlafond/SurfingChungLu.pdf) deals expressly with generating synthetic social network graphs.

consider the given references as somewhat arbitrary choices. i'd expect a vast number of pertinent resources.

some sketchy high-level thoughts of my own: do you have any information on the (statistical) properties of the actual graph, aggregate measures of the weights or their statistical distribution ? do you have any information on the properties of your sampling strategy (notably bias) ? are your observations time-tagged ?

in case you have a statistical model, look into max-likelihood estimation. in case you only have the observed connections so far, and if you can assume they are iid, you may apply a bootstrap method to the set of your observations to estimate statistics of graph properties (eg. mean/variance/etc. of degree/connectedness/girth/weights etc.). depending on the measure in question this track might be overkill - assume your set of observations is not biased and compute the measure from the given graph instead.

feed this information into a random graph generator that allows for initialization with a kick-off graph.

hope this outline helps, as foggy as it is. best regards.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good start for papers.  I am already familiar with graphs somewhat, but for this particular application I'd like a general solution to link interference that isn't dependent on the statistical properties of the network.  That is, I'm not building/growing an artificial network, but I have actual social network data for which I'm essentially trying to replicate Facebook/Google+/LinkedIn's friend suggestion algorithms.  I do have time stamps on all nodes and edges, but I'd prefer not to have to use that level of data.  Link weights for the directed graph should be enough?